# Split a large postgresql dump into smaller files

Tags: bash, postgresql

I have an old postgresql dump that is 1.4GB large containing hundreds of tables and its data.

in the file, there are first all table create statements and then all data inserts.

I can split the file into two using:

```
file_name=synapse.sql

# devider:
STR='-- Data for Name:' 

# number of lines befotre the devider that should get into the bottom file already:
D=2

# get first occurrence of devider:
K=$(grep -n -- $STR $file_name |head -1|cut -d":" -f1)

# line count (N): 
N=$(wc -l < $file_name)

# length of the bottom file:
L=$(( $N - $K + $D))

# create the top of file: 
head -n $K $file_name > top_$file_name

# create bottom of file: 
tail -n $L $file_name > bottom_$file_name
```

(source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3066968/1069083)

the top file now looks like this:

```
--
-- Name: access_tokens; Type: TABLE; Schema: public; Owner: someone
--

CREATE TABLE access_tokens (
    ...
);


ALTER TABLE access_tokens OWNER TO "someone";

--
-- Name: application_services; Type: TABLE; Schema: public; Owner: someone
...
```

Bottom file looks like this:

```
--
-- Data for Name: access_tokens; Type: TABLE DATA; Schema: public; Owner: someone
--

COPY access_tokens (id, user_id, device_id, token, last_used) FROM stdin;
4       @dagobertderkaufhauserpresser:matrix.test.com  \N      MDAxZWxvY2F0aW9uIG1hdHJpeC5lY2xhYnMuZGUKMDAxM2lkZW50aWZpZXIga2V5CjAwMTBjaWQgZ2VuID0gMQowMDQxY2lkIHVzZXJfaWQgPSBAZGFnb2JlcnRkZXJrYXVmaGF1c2VycHJlc3NlcjptYXRyaXguZWNsYWJzLmRlCjAwMTZjaWQgdHlwZSA9IGFjY2VzcwowMDFkY2lkIHRpbWUgPCAxNDU2ODY5OTY0MDk0CjAwMmZzaWduYXR1cmUgqG8q57PffosB-Aob1Szapvu-Bd7j9Sve9-6nPz7hL8QK      \N
5       @wobwob:matrix.test.com        \N      MDAxZWxvY2F0aW9uIG1hdHJpeC5lY2xhYnMuZGUKMDAxM2lkZW50aWZpZXIga2V5CjAwMTBjaWQgZ2VuID0gMQowMDJiY2lkIHVzZXJfaWQgPSBAd29id29iOm1hdHJpeC5lY2xhYnMuZGUKMDAxNmNpZCB0eXBlID0gYWNjZXNzCjAwMWRjaWQgdGltZSA8IDE0NTY4NzM3MTI3NzMKMDAyZnNpZ25hdHVyZSB-PHutqfj3BAB6Mtop5qdiAz70YGSL2Wz7v1w4gj83Zgo  \N
...
```

So how can I split the bottom file now into separate files with the name of the table as filename each?

Comment: Yes, so where's the name of the table? How can we know where to split? Where is the second table we should split at? Is the table name what is found after `Name:`? Is that the only time that `Name:` will appear in an entry?

Comment: Yes, Name is only there. The blocks are all the same, starting like in the excerpts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
csplit -s -f file. bottom_$file_name '/^-- Data for Name:/-1' '{*}'
grep -oP '^-- Data for Name:\s*\K[^;]+' file.* | tr ':' ' ' | xargs -l -t mv
```

In a fresh directory, place your bottom sql file that you generated. Then `csplit` shall split this into multiple files & puts them in `file.nnn` format names. After that we `grep` out the table names from these split files & pass them on to `xargs` to be passed on to `mv`.

Comment: great, this works fine, I additionally changed the file endings with `for i in *; do mv $i $i.sql; done`

Comment: Or we could just replace the `tr` step with this: `sed -e 's/:\(.*\)/ \1.sql/' ` This has the added advantage of not deleting any colons if present in table name & of course saving an additional `mv`.